# Zend PHP debugger: How can I start debugging a page using a get argument?

Tags: php, debugging, zend-studio, zend-debugger

I am trying out the debugger built into `Zend studio`.  It seems great!  One thing though, when I start a page using the debugger does anyone know how I can set a request get argument within the page?

For example, I don't want to debug runtests.php

I want to debug `runtests.php?test=10`

I assume its a simple configuration and I just can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start the debugger on another page, and then change the browser url to what you wanted.
It's not ideal but it should work.

I have high hopes for their next release.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend getting the [Zend Studio Toolbar](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads). The extension allows you to control which pages are debugged from within the browser instead of from Zend Studio.  The options for debugging let you debug the next page, the next form post or all pages.  When you debug like this it runs the PHP just like it will from your server instead of from within Zend Studio. It's an essential tool when using Zend Studio.